# Facebook APIs: Anyway to see when a page was created?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Has Facebook ever provided a way to ascertain when a page was created either through the Graph API, the Legacy API, or FQL? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the creation date of a page isn't exposed anywhere in the API

Answer (score 2):

According to this offical resource :

**https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page**

There is no any column that mention about the time when page is created.