# Facebook FQL page table "Start Info" field

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Where can i find the "Start Info" field in the facebook fql.page table?

Start Info can be found in the ui at
  Edit Page Info > Start Info

FQL - query columns of table page

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, description, type, is_cursor, is_deprecated FROM column WHERE table_name = "page"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **founded** *string* When the company is founded. Applicable to Companies
>
> *Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page*

```
SELECT founded FROM page WHERE page_id = 76283417065
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "founded": "1900"
    }
  ]
}
```

As the documentation indicates, there is only one field relating to the "Start info" form, but it is only available if the page represents a **company**.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there is a field like that in the UI doesn't mean that the API exposed this data. There are sometimes differences between the data that you as a user can see as opposed to the data an application can see via the API.

At this time, [it is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745333/facebook-apis-anyway-to-see-when-a-page-was-created) to get the creation time of a page via the API. The linked answer was posted by a Facebook employee who works on the developer support engineering team.

Comment: It's not the creation time of the page, it is a user defined field.  I was just wondering if someone knew of it's existence in another table or the graph api or something.  I understand facebook doesn't expose everything.